# FileManager.copyItem(at: URL, to: URL) fails without throwing an error

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I've noticed that `FileManager`'s methods for moving and copying items behave differently. `fileManager.moveItem(at: src, to: dst)` throws error if `dst` directory has immutable attribute:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“src” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “dst”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=dst, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move
>   ), NSDestinationFilePath=dst, NSFilePath=src, NSUnderlyingError=0x108b0e190 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

Instead `fileMangaer.copyItem(at: src, to: dst)` doesn't throw any errors. It's only output to console a message:

> Open on dst: Operation not permitted

Is there are any way to copy file with better error handling?

Running on macOS 10.12.5

UPD:

Code example:

```
let dir = "/private/tmp/file-manager-test"
let file = "/private/tmp/file1"

do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: file, contents: Data(), attributes: nil)

    try FileManager.default.setAttributes([.immutable: true], ofItemAtPath: dir)

    let fname = (file as NSString).lastPathComponent
    let dst = (dir as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fname)
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: file, toPath: dst)

} catch let e {

    print("\(e)")
}
```

It works as expected in playground. But if you run this code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` method you will see no exceptions.

UPD2:

I've found similar case on OpenRadar: https://openradar.appspot.com/32083596

Looks like this is system's bug related to `OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE` environment variable.

Comment: That's strange, it's `func copyItem(atPath srcPath: String, toPath dstPath: String) throws` and `func moveItem(atPath srcPath: String, toPath dstPath: String) throws`. They should BOTH throw en error. Also, note that if you implements the delegate method `fileManager(_:shouldProceedAfterError:copyingItemAtPath:toPath:)`, is it called?

Comment: I've added code example with some notes.

Comment: Try using `URL`s instead of `String`s. Filemanager sometimes struggles with `String` paths.

Comment: I've tried to use `URL`. No luck.